# Angular2 Material DatePicker Customize

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How can i customize labels in datepicker? Such as the example below:

[image]

I want to display `FunnyDay` instead of `Monday`, or `SunnyMonth` instead of `September`.

Answer (score 0):

You can localize all the labels and messages using [`MdDatepickerIntl`](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api).

> Localizing labels and messages ([source](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#localizing-labels-and-messages))
>
> The various text strings used by the datepicker are provided through `MdDatepickerIntl`. Localization of these messages can be done by providing a subclass with translated values in your application root module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [MdDatepickerModule, MdNativeDateModule],
  providers: [
    {provide: MdDatepickerIntl, useClass: MyIntl},
  ],
})
export class MyApp {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom implementation of [DateAdapter](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/datetime/date-adapter.ts#L21) (provide your cool names by [DateAdapter#getDayOfWeekNames](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/datetime/date-adapter.ts#L75) and [DateAdapter#getMonthNames](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/datetime/date-adapter.ts#L62)) and provide it as usual:

```
{provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CoolDateAdapter},
```

You can use [NativeDateAdapter](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/datetime/native-date-adapter.ts#L61) as an example or even extend your CoolDateAdapter by it (this way you will need to override two target methods above).